# Vehicle light problems 101 (2000 buick century)

Tags: headlight, lights

How can  make really dim brights brighter. And the dash light doesn't  turn on (the prnd and mileage lights). I've jumped  my car once when it died and they all turned on but they never did after that. The speed needle lights up  and so does the gas but the bottom half doesnt

Comment: How are the fuses? It might be that the fuse for the dashboard lights/interior lighting has blown.

Comment: Would that let the spedometer  and gas light on the dash light up or are they 2 different  fuses

Comment: The signal for the speedo and fuel level gauge come from the vehicle speed sensor and fuel level sensor. It is quite possible that they are on a separate circuit and that their light source comes from another source (so 2 different fuses is a possibility). If you have a wiring diagram you could confirm this.

Comment: I'll look in the fuse box when I get home but it doesn't make sense  how it turned on randomly when it got jumped

Comment: I see.. I was assuming that they were working before the jumpstart. How's your battery's voltage while the car is running?

Comment: Yeah I figured but that's okay,  I'm assuming good,  my volt Guage wouldn't   turn on  so I'm not positive.  Everything but that light turns on.

Comment: I suggest you should test it with a multimeter across the battery with the engine running.

Answer (score 3):

You are describing symptoms of a bad ground in your electrical system.

Check your ground on the battery. The negative post.  Make sure you have a solid connection. The clamp on the negative shouldn't wiggle or have any play in it. Check for corrosion. The white powdery substance.  If you find any remove the battery post clamp from the wire and use baking soda mixed with water to clean the clamp, the post and the wire. Do the same with the positive side.

Check the grounding wire from the battery to the chassis or engine and validate that it is secure and **free of corrosion**.  Check the grounding bolt for corrosion and clean with baking soda solution.

Use the baking soda solution liberally in your efforts.  Validate secure connections for both sides of your battery negative wire (vehicle ground) and the positive.

When are you are done using the baking soda solution rinse it off with water and dry.  Use an old disposable rag to do it, any remnants of battery acid will degrade the rag into tatters.

Good luck.

Comment: I'll do this tomorrow  and update  with results hopefully  it works